# JScriptTypeInfo definition

Tags: vbscript, javascript, scriptcontrol

I have the following code in VBScript:

```
 Dim control
 set control = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
 control.language = "jscript"
 control.addCode("function test() { return {property: 'test'}; };")
 Dim result
 set result = control.Eval("test();")
```

I know that the object returned to `result` is of the type `JScriptTypeInfo` but I can't find any information regarding the definition of this type and doing similar code in Visual Studio C# only shows this up as `{System.__ComObject}` in the locals pane.

Does anyone know what the interface to the `JScriptTypeInfo` type is?

Comment: I have answered this question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711112/in-excel-vba-on-windows-for-parsed-json-variables-what-is-this-jscripttypeinfo

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you what I did to deal with this type, since I had access to the original JScript classic ASP pages that I was reading. The JScriptTypeInfo object was created when a `new String()` statement (ex: `Session( "Data" ) = new String( "Test");`) was used in the ASP page. If the session object was created with just a `String()` statement (ex: `Session( "Data" ) = String( "Test");`), then VB.NET can convert the type just fine.

For what it's worth.