# In Excel VBA on Windows, for parsed JSON variables what is this JScriptTypeInfo anyway?

Tags: json, excel, vba

answering my own question here.
I have done some work with JSON in Excel VBA and lots of findings to post which I will do so in Q & A format
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

So elsewhere on stackoverflow one can see questions about parsing JSON in VBA but they seem to miss a trick or two.

To begin with, I resile from using custom JSON parsing libraries and instead use the ScriptControl's Eval method as the basis of all my JSON code.
And also we express a preference from native Microsoft solutions.

Here is a prior question [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to mitigate issue of dot syntax traversal of parsed JSON broken by IDE's capitalisation behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710995/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-mitigate-issue-of-dot-syntax-traversal-of-parsed) upon which this question builds.  It shows how using VBA.CallByName is more robust
than using the dot syntax to traverse a parsed JSON object.  Also another prior question [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to loop through a JSON array parsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711034/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-parsed) shows how it also can
be used to access array elements.  But CallByName returns a curious variable type that appears in Watch window as Object/JScriptTypeInfo
and if one type Debug.Print in the immediate window (or hovers over the variable) one gets the uninformative "[object Object]".  In another question
in the series [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to get stringified JSON respresentation instead of “[object Object]” for parsed JSON variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711073/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-get-stringified-json-respresentation-instead-of) I present some debugging "sugar" that allows nice inspection of variables.   In a fourth question [In Windows Excel VBA,how to get JSON keys to pre-empt “Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711100/in-windows-excel-vba-how-to-get-json-keys-to-pre-empt-run-time-error-438-obj), whilst investigating
how to query a JSON object for a member I discover a hasOwnProperty() method that seems attached to a JScriptTypeInfo object.

So in this question I ask, what exactly is this JScriptTypeInfo anyway?

This is Question 5 of series of 5.  Here is the full series

Q1 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to mitigate issue of dot syntax traversal of parsed JSON broken by IDE's capitalisation behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710995/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-mitigate-issue-of-dot-syntax-traversal-of-parsed)

Q2 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to loop through a JSON array parsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711034/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-parsed)

Q3 [In Excel VBA on Windows, how to get stringified JSON respresentation instead of “[object Object]” for parsed JSON variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711073/in-excel-vba-on-windows-how-to-get-stringified-json-respresentation-instead-of)

Q4 [In Windows Excel VBA,how to get JSON keys to pre-empt “Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711100/in-windows-excel-vba-how-to-get-json-keys-to-pre-empt-run-time-error-438-obj)

Q5 [In Excel VBA on Windows, for parsed JSON variables what is this JScriptTypeInfo anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711112/in-excel-vba-on-windows-for-parsed-json-variables-what-is-this-jscripttypeinfo)

Comment: WSH JScript global object type is `JScriptTypeInfo` (that is global `this` object in other words). BTW, VBScript has the same global object `Me` of type `VBScriptTypeInfo`, and it allows dynamically create procedures, functions, classes, and even classes within functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible place to look is in the type library for the ScriptControl as this is the library which emanates this type.

The full details of this type on my machine are

```
Libary Name:    Microsoft Script Control 1.0 (Ver 1.0)       
LIBID:          {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}
Location:       C:\wINDOWS\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx
```

Using both VBA IDE's Object Browser and OLEVIEW.exe which disassembles type library I can no trace of the interface JScriptTypeInfo or the method hasOwnProperty.

But isn't it the case that the script engine hosts language implementations, such as VBScript and JScript (Microsoft name for Javascript).
So perhaps we should hunt for a JScript implementation DLL and indeed there is one here are details

```
Libary Name:    Microsoft JScript Globals
LIBID:          {3EEF9759-35FC-11D1-8CE4-00C04FC2B085}
Location:       C:\wINDOWS\SysWOW64\jscript.dll
```

which on my machine is not registered and so not in my list of Tools->References libraries or in OLEVIEW.exe.  I was lucky to find whilst poking around.
Here is some output from OLEVIEW giving an exceprt of the type library

```
[
  uuid(3EEF9758-35FC-11D1-8CE4-00C04FC2B097)
]
dispinterface ObjectInstance {
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(0x0000044c)]
        StringInstance* toString();
        [id(0x0000044d)]
        StringInstance* toLocaleString();
        [id(0x0000044e)]
        VARIANT hasOwnProperty(VARIANT propertyName);
        [id(0x0000044f)]
        VARIANT propertyIsEnumerable(VARIANT propertyName);
        [id(0x00000450)]
        VARIANT isPrototypeOf(VARIANT obj);
        [id(0x00000451)]
        ObjectInstance* valueOf();
};
```

This above shows the hasOwnProperty to be a method of a IDispatch interface (or dispinterface) necessary to work with VBA object's declared of type Object (e.g. `Dim foo as Object`)
Registering the type library with regsvr32 appears to do nothing.  One must browse to the file in Tools References to view in VBA's object browser.

We can be pretty sure about this JScript.dll file because using Process Explorer we can see the dll being loaded when executing the line `oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"`
In the lack of a registered type library I loaded the file JScript.dll into Notepad++ and searched for .J.S.c.r.i.p.t.T.y.p.e.I.n.f.o as a regular expression and found a hit.  Bingo!

Not only is there an ObjectInstance which would describe most of the variables a VBA program encounters but also there is an ArrayInstance which is intriguing, perhaps we can use Javascript's own array functions
or at least a subset as documented in JScript.dll's type library.  Here is some sample code

```
'Tools->References->
'Microsoft Script Control 1.0;  {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx

'and FYI/browsing capabilities       Microsoft JScript Globals;   C:\wINDOWS\SysWOW64\jscript.dll

Option Explicit

Private Sub TestJSONParsingWithCallByName5()

    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
    oScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

    Dim sJsonString(0 To 1) As String
    sJsonString(0) = "{'key1': 'value1'  ,'key2': { 'key3': 'value3' } }"
    sJsonString(1) = "[ 1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678, 6789 ]"



    Dim objJSON(0 To 1) As Object
    Set objJSON(0) = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString(0) + ")")
    Set objJSON(1) = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + sJsonString(1) + ")")

    Debug.Assert objJSON(0).hasOwnProperty("key1")
    Debug.Assert objJSON(0).hasOwnProperty("key2")

    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "length", VbGet) = 6
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "0", VbGet) = "1234"

    '* Is objJSON(1) an ArrayInstance?
    '* does it support the reverse method of the ArrayInstance object?

    'Call objJSON(1).Reverse  '* reverse gets capitalised into Reverse ... grrrr
    Call CallByName(objJSON(1), "reverse", VbMethod) '* so use CallByName as solution to "helpful" capitalisation

    '* Yes, the elements are reversed!

    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "length", VbGet) = 6
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "0", VbGet) = "6789"

    Stop

    '** And now we know objJSON(1) is an ArrayInstance we can have some fun with array operations

    Dim objSplice As Object
    Set objSplice = CallByName(objJSON(1), "splice", VbMethod, 2, 1)
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "length", VbGet) = 5
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objSplice, "length", VbGet) = 1

    Dim objSlice As Object
    Set objSlice = CallByName(objJSON(1), "slice", VbMethod, 2)
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "length", VbGet) = 5
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objSlice, "length", VbGet) = 3

    Stop
    Call CallByName(objJSON(1), "sort", VbMethod)


    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "join", VbMethod) = "1234,2345,3456,5678,6789"
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "join", VbMethod, " ") = "1234 2345 3456 5678 6789"
    Stop


    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "pop", VbMethod) = "6789"
    Debug.Assert CallByName(objJSON(1), "length", VbGet) = 4
    Stop
End Sub
```

SUMMARY: JScriptTypeInfo is something to show in the VBA IDE watch window and the return of the VBA function TypeName() but which really hides a number of objects that can be found in JScript.dll.
I suppose it can be described as polymorphic, perhaps better to describe it as late binding.  To view capabilities use Tools-References and browse to JScript.dll.

Comment: Is the type `JScriptTypeInfo ` really defined in `JScript.dll`? When I opened this dll in OLEVIEW no such type is defined there.

Comment: @dee: Thanks for question. I think ITypeInfo is a key COM interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221442(v=vs.85).aspx and is relevant not just to type libraries but also exported from IDispatch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221571(v=vs.85).aspx Javascript is dynamic and so it would make sense not to place so much in a static type library as members of an object are created 'on the fly'.  Perhaps I will revisit text of the answer but I am revisiting COM interfaces at the moment and so will be better place soon to give an updated answer.

Comment: OK, thank you! The type `JScriptTypeInfo` is a little mysterious, I was not able to find any reasonable information about it except this answer.

Comment: Cool stuff here! One thing to note is that the ability to create a ScriptControl COM object is limited to 32-Bit using `CreateObject("ScriptControl")`. Instead you need to use [mshta x86 host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134477/6302131)

Comment: @Sancarn: I'm using 64-bit no problem.

Comment: @SMeaden I am uncertain how because as Wolfgang Kuehn said in the other forum, scriptcontrol is a 32bit component only and will not run inside a 64bit process. I've experienced this issue many times in the past, and thus have always avoided script control. Didn't know there was this work around though.

Comment: @Sancarn: It's an old problem, there was a 16 vs 32 bit issue twenty years ago https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows and same solution is there for 32 vs 64 bit, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system .  Look for Wow6432Node in your registry.