# VBA Retrieving items from array returning same item

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Coming from JS, I've realized the methods for working with arrays in VBA are very minimal. Because of this, I've created this mess of code to find the index of certain items within 2D arrays. The basic idea of this code is to go through a bunch of open reports, store them in an array, and pull them out based on how they match to the current date in the master report. The code runs, but it repeatedly does the operation on the first item of the `wkbArray` *only*. When I tried to use the loop counters to track array positions, that didn't work. So I created counters independent of those, but that doesn't seem to work either, as they just stay at zero the whole time. Any ideas of a better way to keep track of indices for 2D arrays is much appreciated. I don't expect anyone to go through all this code, I'm just including it all so you can see the logic I'm attempting to use to navigate these arrays.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Integer
Dim i, t, j, z, r, k, w, f, u, e, d, v, n, p, b, aa As Integer
Dim yesCount As Integer
Dim finalArrayCount As Integer
Dim lastDBRow As Integer
Dim lastMacroRow As Long
Dim verylastDBRow As Integer
Dim bookName As String
Dim bookDate As String
Dim dateString As String
Dim activePaste As String
Dim matchDate As String
Dim startColumn As Long
startColumn = (Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database(CU's)").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) + 1
Dim bookCount As Integer
bookCount = Application.Workbooks.Count - 2
Dim wkbArray() As String
Dim duplicateArray() As Variant
Dim finalArray() As Variant
ReDim wkbArray((bookCount - 1), 1) As String

'Loop through each workbook, store book name and date from X2 in a 2d array'

Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("macroPaste").Visible = True

i = 0
For Each wkb In Workbooks
    If Left(wkb.Name, 15) = "CP_Inventory_By" Then

        dateString = wkb.ActiveSheet.Range("X2").Value
        bookName = wkb.Name
        bookDate = Left(dateString, 5)

        'Add book name and date to array'

        wkbArray(i, 0) = bookName
        wkbArray(i, 1) = bookDate
        i = i + 1
    Else
    End If
Next wkb



'create loop to specify number of times to run paste operation'

For t = 1 To bookCount
    matchDate = Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("Database(CU's)").Cells(1, startColumn).Value

        'Find book name based on match date'
        d = 0
        n = 0
        For j = 0 To (bookCount - 1)
            If wkbArray(d, 1) = matchDate Then
            n = n + d
            End If
            d = d + 1
        Next j

        activePaste = wkbArray(n, 0)
        With Workbooks(activePaste).Sheets("CP_Inventory_By_Run_Date_Email")
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        'Set macroPaste Range equal to activePaste range, filter criteria.'

        Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("macroPaste").Range(Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("macroPaste").Cells(1, 1), Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("macroPaste").Cells(lastRow, 24)).Value = Workbooks(activePaste).Sheets("CP_Inventory_By_Run_Date_Email").Range(Workbooks(activePaste).Sheets("CP_Inventory_By_Run_Date_Email").Cells(1, 1), Workbooks(activePaste).Sheets("CP_Inventory_By_Run_Date_Email").Cells(lastRow, 24)).Value

        With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("macroPaste")
            lastMacroRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastMacroRow, 24)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=.Range("AA1:AA12"), Unique:=False
            .UsedRange.Copy
        End With

        'Paste in daily paste sheet,

        With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Daily Data")
            .Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            currentLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            yesCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(currentLastRow, 3)), "Yes")
        End With



        'Create Array of "YES Database Items'
        If yesCount > 0 Then
            With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Daily Data")

                ReDim duplicateArray(yesCount, 2) As Variant
                r = 0

                For z = 2 To currentLastRow
                    If .Cells(z, 3).Value = "Yes" Then
                        duplicateArray(r, 0) = .Cells(z, 5).Value
                        duplicateArray(r, 1) = .Cells(z, 6).Value
                        duplicateArray(r, 2) = .Cells(z, 9).Value
                        r = r + 1
                    Else
                    End If
                Next z
            End With

            'Create final array with unique YES items'
            ReDim finalArray(yesCount, 2) As Variant
            finalArrayCount = 0
            k = 0
            f = 0
            'Figure our how many times to loop through duplicate array'
            p = 0
            For k = 0 To yesCount
                'Figure out if the value is already in the final array'
                v = 0
                aa = 0
                For f = 0 To yesCount
                    If finalArray(aa, 1) = duplicateArray(p, 1) Then
                    v = v + 1
                    End If
                    aa = aa + 1
                Next f
                'if the value isn't in the final array, then add it. Otherwise, next k
                If v = 1 Then
                    finalArray(p, 1) = duplicateArray(p, 1)
                    finalArray(p, 0) = duplicateArray(p, 0)
                    finalArray(p, 2) = duplicateArray(p, 2)
                    finalArrayCount = finalArrayCount + 1
                    p = p + 1
                End If

            Next k

            'Add new values from finalArray to bottom of DatabaseCU sheet'
            e = 0
            b = 0
            With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("Database(CU's)")
                lastDBRow = (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row) + 1
                    For e = 0 To finalArrayCount - 1
                        .Cells(lastDBRow, 2).Value = finalArray(b, 0)
                        .Cells(lastDBRow, 3).Value = finalArray(b, 1)
                        .Cells(lastDBRow, 4).Value = finalArray(b, 2)
                        lastDBRow = lastDBRow + 1
                        b = b + 1
                    Next e
            End With
        End If

        'fill down formula and move to next sheet'


        With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("Database(CU's)")
            verylastDBRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(2, startColumn), .Cells(2, startColumn)).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, startColumn), .Cells(verylastDBRow, startColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault
            .Range(.Cells(2, startColumn), .Cells(verylastDBRow, startColumn)).Copy
            .Range(.Cells(2, startColumn), .Cells(verylastDBRow, startColumn)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With

        'Clear daily paste
        With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Daily Data")
            .Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(currentLastRow, 28)).Clear
        End With

        'clear macro paste
        With Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("macroPaste")
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastMacroRow, 24)).Clear
            On Error Resume Next
            .ShowAllData
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        'Erase Arrays
        Erase finalArray, duplicateArray

        startColumn = startColumn + 1
Next t

Workbooks("CP Inventory Metrics with Pallets new.xlsm").Sheets("macroPaste").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is working then this question would be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com  If it is not working please state which line is throwing the error.

Comment: I'm not getting any runtime errors, but for some reason using counter variables in the array calls isn't working, as it finds the same record every time even though it should be changing.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array functions are available in Excel VBA via the JScript plugin.

I direct you to this article.

[In Excel VBA on Windows, for parsed JSON variables what is this JScriptTypeInfo anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711112/in-excel-vba-on-windows-for-parsed-json-variables-what-is-this-jscripttypeinfo/37711113#37711113)

Scroll down the lowest part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the j loop otherwise it will always exit with the same value

```
'Find book name based on match date'
d = 0
n = 0
For j = 0 To (bookCount - 1)
    If wkbArray(d, 1) = matchDate Then
      n = n + d
      exit for 'here
    End If
    d = d + 1
Next j

'You will then pick up the nth workbook in
activePaste = wkbArray(n, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After a few hours of stepping through each line one by one, I realized I had a huge logic flaw; one of the strings was formatted differently, thus the if statement was never evaluating as true, and "n" reset to zero every time which is why I was getting the same record every time. Oh, the triumph I feel!