# scraping web vba oncick

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, onclick

in the link https://www.forebet.com/en/predictions-tips-atl%C3%A9tico-madrid-real-madrid-553878 I want to load the document that is on the page that you click on "uo_t_butt"

I create the script with

```
Sub provaonclick()

Dim objIE As Object
Dim ele As Object
Dim ele1 As Object


Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.forebet.com/it/pronostico-per-real-madrid-liverpool-fc-731893"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("tabs-ul")(0)
Set ele1 = ele.document.getElementById("uo_t_butt").Click

End Sub
```

but in the object ele1 there is nothing

Comment: You question is unclear. You said `click on "uo_t_butt"` but never did clarify what is `uo_t_butt`. Is this a class or id or something else? Moreover, the link within your script and the link in your description are different. Try to edit your question to clear the confusion @plinius.

Answer (score 1):

What i think is your problem is that it is a javascript controlling the button.

HTML and javascript isn't my strong suit but the following code works for me:

```
Sub provaonclick()
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.forebet.com/it/pronostico-per-real-madrid-liverpool-fc-731893"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

With objIE.Document.getElementById("uo_t_butt")
    .Focus
    .Click
End With

End Sub
```

".Focus" made the code work for me. I don't know what it does though.

EDIT: Actually not using set in front of "objIE.Document.getElementById("uo_t_butt").click" was the difference.

Comment: Because as per my answer, you have removed the .Click which was producing the  JScriptTypeInfo object.

Comment: Yes is see you've changed your answer and explained a bit. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't normally set an element and try to do a click on it at the same time.
The `Set` keyword is for assigning a reference.  It is necessary to distinguish between assignment of an object and assignment of the default property of the object. It is this reference type you will be passing around.

This:

```
Set ele1 = ele.document.getElementById("uo_t_butt").Click
```

Normally, this would have thrown an error. Weirdly there is a javascript item generated which is `JScriptTypeInfo`. This , according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37711113/6241235), likely

> hides a number of objects that can be found in JScript.dll.

Remove the action (`.Click`) from the end to set an object in the normal way and you don't need the preliminary object. Work direct of `document` with the id.

I had no problem using id with:

```
objIE.document.querySelector("#uo_t_butt").Click
```

You can use an attribute = value CSS selector

```
objIE.document.querySelector("[onclick*='uo']").Click
```

This switches to the unders/overs tab.

[image]

Could also use:

```
objIE.document.querySelector("[id='uo_t_butt']").Click
```

Comment: sorry was my mistake I wanted to load all the document instead of the click command, actually click and I load the page in the open browser and I solved it so ele.document.getElementById("uo_t_butt").Click

Comment: Which is the answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub provaonclick()
Dim objIE As Object
Dim ele As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.forebet.com/it/pronostico-per-real-madrid-liverpool-fc-731893"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
objIE.document.getElementById("uo_t_butt").Click

Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("schema")(1)
Stop
End Sub
```

sorry all I thought I had solved but my macro just click on "onclick" but does not load the new page in "ele".
In "ele" I find the first page that opens not the clicked one